# uwp data binding: how to listen to any change of Grid.WidthProperty

Tags: xaml, data-binding, uwp, windows-10-universal

Say I have a `Grid` and a `Line` inside that `Grid` . 
I want the `Line`'s Width to be same as the `Grid`'s Width all the time. So, I bound them

```
<Page
    x:Class="GeoDraw.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:GeoDraw"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:x1="using:System"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Background="#FF262626" RequestedTheme="Dark" Loaded="Page_Loaded">

    <Grid x:Name="grid" BorderBrush="#FFE02121" Margin="20" Background="#FFD69696">
        <Line Stroke="White" Y1="20" Y2="20" X1="0" X2="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=ActualWidth}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

the line initially takes the width of the grid, but changing the grid's size doesn't change the Line's width.
How can I bind those properties correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the implementation which you are looking for but if you really want that behavior you could always define an event handler to respond to your Grid `SizeChanged` event, and update the Line `X2` property in code-behind:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" BorderBrush="#FFE02121" Margin="20" Background="#FFD69696" SizeChanged="grid_SizeChanged">
   <Line x:Name="myline" Stroke="White" Y1="20" Y2="20" X1="0" X2="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=grid, Mode=OneTime}" />
</Grid>
```

Update your `Line` in the EventHandler,

```
private void grid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
   myline.X2 = grid.ActualWidth;
}
```

Not only wasn't I obtaining any kind of binding error expression, but binding to the `ActualWidth` dependency property was not working for other controls, such as `TextBox`, for instance.

It became more apparent that the reason was pointing to a particular behaviour of the ActualWidth dependency property, rather than anything else. 
While checking out the `ActualWidth` documentation ([ActualWidth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_ActualWidth)) on the FrameworkElement class, found evidence which supports this approach.

> > Although it has an ActualWidthProperty backing field, ActualWidth does
> >     not raise property change notifications and it should be thought of as
> >     a regular CLR property and not a dependency property.
>
> ...
>
> > For purposes of ElementName binding, ActualWidth does not post updates
> >     when it changes (due to its asynchronous and run-time calculated
> >     nature). Do not attempt to use ActualWidth as a binding source for an
> >     ElementName binding. If you have a scenario that requires updates
> >     based on ActualWidth, use a SizeChanged handler.

Looking back onto the `Binding` definition above, I changed the Binding Mode from its Default `OneWay` to `OneTime`, to only calculate the initial dimension for the `X2` property when the UI is first shown, since there is no reason to "waste" resources trying to "observe" an `ActualWidth` value modification when at the source we will never be signaled of any modification. 
Or you could always, set the initial value in `code-behind` as well.

Comment: exactly!! I was wondering about the `TextBox` too. Now I understand. Many thanks Andre :)